# Как задать excluded['disable'] только для textarea где прикручен ckeditor bootstrapvalidator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, валидация

На форме есть hidden поля, когда использую excluded:[':disabled'] для того чтобы валидировался CKEDITOR, hidden поле не валидируется. Если использовать excluded:[':disabled', ':hidden'] то с hidden полем всё в порядке, то есть оно валидируется когда не hidden и не валидируется когда hidden, НО ПРИ ЭТОМ валидация CKEDITOR не работает. Если у hidden поле поставить excluded:false, то он не валидируется вообще, а нужно чтоб валидировался когда не hidden(то есть он меняется динамически на странице)